# Estimate the parameters of a random variable which is the sum of Uniform Random Variables using PyMC

Tags: statistics, pymc

I am trying to use PyMC to estimate the parameters of my model. However I am unable to understand how one estimates the parameters of a model which is not a standard distribution but perhaps a sum or a function of some other distributions.

Example:
Lets say I have data "Data" generated by a process which is a sum of 2 Random Variables X and Y which are both drawn from Uniform Distributions with parameters (a, b) and (c,d) respectively. I would like to model this using PyMC and estimate back the parameters a, b,c, and d. I am able to setup the priors for the parameters but am not sure how to specify the observed variable and bind it to the observed data.

If the Distribution of the observed variable was standard (say O) I would just do:

```
obs = pm.DistO(params, observed= True, value=data)
```

but this is not the case. Can I model this scenario in PyMC at all ?

Python code I am using below:

```
import numpy as np
import pymc as pm


# Generate the synthetic data
a = 2.0   
b = 8.0
c = 6.0
d = 10.0
d1 = np.random.uniform(a, b, 100)  
d2 = np.random.uniform(c, d, 100) 
data = d1 + d2

# Now lets try to recover the parameters.

#Setup the priors

# data is observed. Now lets recover the params
p_a = pm.Normal("pa", 0.0, 10.0)
p_b = pm.Normal("pb", 0.0, 10.0)  
p_c = pm.Normal("pc", 0.0, 10.0)
p_d = pm.Normal("pd", 0.0, 10.0)
p_d1 = pm.Uniform("pd1", p_a, p_b)
p_d2 = pm.Uniform("pd2", p_c, p_d)


# Here is where I am confused ?
# p_data = p_d1 + p_d2 
# How to now specify that p_data's value is observed (the observations are in "data")

#TODO: Use MCMC to sample and obtain traces
```

Comment: This is an unusual model, are you sure it is the one you are after?

Comment: No the above is just an example. I want to know how to estimate the parameters of a distribution which is not standard, but can be expressed a function of other distributions (in this case sum), given that I have observed data. I am just trying to get familiar with PyMC and learn more about Bayesian methods and dont yet have a real world problem I want to model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* model this scenario in PyMC2, and in a sense it is easy to do so. But it is also hard to do, so I will demonstrate a solution for the special case of a model where $b-a = d-c$.

I say it is easy because PyMC2 can use an arbitrary function as a data log-likelihood, using the `observed` decorator.  For example:

```
@pm.observed
def pdata(value=data, pa=pa, pb=pb, pc=pc, pd=pd):
    logpr = 0.
    # code to calculate logpr from data and parameters
    return logpr
```

It is not easy because you have to come up with the code to calculate logpr, and I find that complicated and error-prone for cases like the sum of two uniforms.  This code will also be in the inner loop of the MCMC, so efficiency is important.

If the data were from a single uniform with unknown support, you could use the decorator approach as follows:

```
@pm.observed
def pdata(value=data, pa=pa, pb=pb, pc=pc, pd=pd):
    return pm.uniform_like(value, pa, pb)
```

In the special case of your model where the uniforms have the same width, the data likelihood is proportional to a triangular distribution, and you can write it out with only a moderate amount of pain:

```
@pm.observed
def pdata(value=data, pa=pa, pb=pb, pc=pc, pd=pd):
    pd = pc + (pb - pa)  # don't use pd value

    # make sure order is acceptible
    if pb < pa or pd < pc:
        return -np.inf

    x = value
    pr = \
        np.where(x < pa+pc, 0,
                 np.where(x <= (pa+pb+pc+pd)/2, x - (pa+pc),
                          np.where(x <= (pb+pd), (pb+pd) - x,
                                   0))) \
            / (.5 * ((pb+pd) - (pa+pc)) * ((pb-pa) + (pd-pc))/2)
    return np.sum(np.log(pr))
```

For the general sum-of-two-uniforms you posted, the distribution is trapezoidal, and writing it out is more work than I am up for.  [Approximate Bayesian Computation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_Bayesian_computation) (ABC) is a promising approach for situations where it is too much work to compute the log-likelihood explicitly.

Here is [a notebook collecting this all up](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/aflaxman/cb43e6b876ec78cb7ec4).

Answer (score 1):

I will just go ahead and point out a couple of things that you may find interesting.

The parameters of your model are not [identifiable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifiability). There is a closed-form density that you can use to write down a likelihood. I used Mathematica to compute it in one minute and avoid some tedious computations. You can see the result below as a function of z (a realization of Z := X + Y).[image: Closed-form density]

Once you have values for z, this density can - in principle - be maximized numerically. In practice, although you can have a simple estimate of the upper bound of (b - a) and (d - c), without further structure you cannot conclude anything precise. Note, in fact, that {a = 2, b = 3, c = -2, d = -1} results in a density identical to the density that you would get with {a = 0, b = 1, c = 0, d = 1}. Again, should you be interested, read up on identifiability.

Finally, while in general I will strongly advocate adopting a Bayesian approach, if you are unfamiliar with issues such as the one I pointed out you may be fooling yourself with inaccurate/irrelevant estimates. The frequentist approach via ML, by contrast, will just fail and put the problem very much in your face.

Comment: cool symbolic computation!  can you automatically generate a python representation analogous to the one I did by hand for the special case above?